# Partial Differential Equation and Additivity of Entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, differential-equations

In *A STUDENT'S GUIDE TO ENTROPY* by Don S. Lemons, the author derives how entropy depends on energy and temperature as follows;

Due to the additivity, "the entropy increment of the composite system is the sum of the entropy increments of its parts: $f(T,Q)=2f(T, \frac{Q}{2})$" where $Q$ is the heat absorbed by the system and $T$ is the temperature. "If instead of dividing the heart reservoir into two identical parts we divide it into $n$ identical parts, then

$f(T,Q)=nf(T,\frac{Q}{n})$"

The solution can be obtained by "taking the partial derivative of this with respect to $n$, and solving the resulting partial differential equation", and we have,

$f(T,Q)=g(T)Q$

Taking a partial derivative with respect to $n$, I got $nf(T,\frac{Q}{n})=Q\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{n}}(T,\frac{Q}{n})$. I tried to see if we can separate the variables by $f(T,\frac{Q}{n})=g(T)h(\frac{Q}{n})$, but this got me nowhere.

Any help would be appreciated as to how to solve the above partial differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a differential equation. The  equation 
$$
f(T,Q)=n f(T,Q/n)
$$
holds for any $n$, not just whole numbers. So just take $n=aQ$ (where the constant $a$ has   dimensions
Joules$^{-1}$ so the units   match) to get 
$$
f(T,Q)= aQf(T,1/a)
$$
Then set $af(T,1/a)=g(T)$.  Thus
$$
f(T,Q)= g(T)Q.
$$